# Reuse docker cache from another machine

Tags: docker, caching

Assume I have a docker image, with layers **A B C**, built on **computer1** with the following command
`build -t test_caching .`
And uploaded to my registry.

I pull the image on **computer2** (same architecture x86, same version of docker 24.0.7),
I slighty modify the dockerfile to add some new operation at the end, thus creating layer D.
I try to rebuild the image, **using the previous image as cache**, on computer2.
`docker build --cache-from test_caching -t test_caching .`

However the image **is rebuilt from scratch**, docker seems unable to reuse the previous cache **A B C**, probaby because it comes from another computer.
How to fix this ?

Comment: I think I found a solution with builkit. computer A:
`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --pull --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 -t test_caching .` then computerB:
`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --pull --cache-from test_caching -t test_caching .`

and then